# Deleting an element from an array and then keeping its state for future use without using global variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, state

Say I have an array as defined as the following:

```
var str = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
```

I have a button that, when the user clicks on it, should delete the first element of the string and returns the resulting array after removal (i.e. `['e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`).  The resulting array should also be saved that the next time when the button is pressed, the next following element in the array is deleted (i.e. resulting array will be `['l', 'l', 'o']`) and so forth until all the elements are removed.

This is extremely simple to do if the array is global:

```
var str = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];

function remove_first(the_array) {
    the_array.shift();
    return the_array;
}

del.onclick = function() {
    result = remove_first(str);
}
```

But I want to do this without making the array global.  How would you do this?

Comment: `str = str.slice(1);`

Comment: `str` should be named `arr` :D Above method also works on (real) strings : `'hello'.slice(1) -> "ello"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make the array a global variable.

Simply using Javascript closures capability, you can do the same thing.

```
var functionForClosure = function () {

    var str = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];

    function remove_first(the_array) {
        the_array.shift();
        return the_array;
    }

    del.onclick = function() {
        result = remove_first(str);
    }
};
functionForClosure();
```

There str variable is accesible to your onclick function there; str is not global, but local to the functionForClosure function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the array outside the event handler, since it has to persist between calls of the event handler.

But you don't have to define the array or functions in global scope to make this work, any shared scope is fine. So you can use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to create a new scope:

```
(function() {

    var str = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];

    function remove_first(the_array) {
        the_array.shift();
        return the_array;
    }

    del.onclick = function() {
        var result = remove_first(str); // don't forget `var` here
    }

}());
```

Comment: Ah yeah, almost forgot about the "var".  Thanks.

Comment: This works but can you explain in short why it works?  Not too familiar with IIFE.

Comment: Calling a function creates a new scope. Variables declared in a function are local to a function and hence not global. An IIFE is just a function that is immediately called after it was defined. You typically do this if you don't want a reference of the function around. I could also have written `function foo() {/* your code here */}; foo()`. But since I don't need `foo` later on, there is no need to do that. For more information about IIFEs, follow the link in the answer ("IIFE" is a link in case you don't see it).

Comment: Ah thank you, I did read your link and I looked up a bit about IIFE.  Indeed, as you said, there is the alternative way of writing it which Ramón's did.  I'm going to mark his as correct since I understand that format better.  But the information provided is great.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a javascript closure?

```
var ns = (function () {
    var str = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
        removeFirst = function () { 
            str.shift(); 
            return str; 
        };

    return {
        str: str,
        removeFirst: removeFirst
    };
}());

del.onclick = function () {
    result = ns.removeFirst();
    // console.log(ns.str) to see the result of str
}
```